# C++: How to save platform independent binary files?

Tags: c++, serialization, binaryfiles, platform-independent

I have a 3D-volume, represented as as vector of vector of vector of float, that I want to save to a binary file. (It's a density volume reconstructed from X-ray images that come from a CT scanner.)

Now, I could do this in the following way:

```
        //iterate through the volume
        for (int x = 0; x < _xSize; ++x){
            for (int y = 0; y < _ySize; ++y){
                for (int z = 0; z < _zSize; ++z){
                    //save one float of data
                    stream.write((char*)&_volume[x][y][z], sizeof(float));
                }
            }
        }
```

This basically works. However, I'm asking myself to which extent this is platform independent. I would like to produce a file which is identical regardless of the system it was created on. So there might be machines running Windows, Linux or Mac, they might have 32bit or 64bit word lenght and little endian or big endian byte order.

I suppose if I did this the way it was done above this wouldn't be the case. Now how could I achieve this? I've heard about serialisation but I haven't found a concrete solution for this instance.

Comment: By *not* using binary formats. There are many nice text formats available, and if nothing fits you it's easy to make up your own specialized for your application.

Comment: Binary formats: Specify every bit what your file should be, and then start reading for every platform how you can read/write exactly this format. Exact bit layout of ints and floats, charsets etc,etc. Yes, it´s complicated. Btw. the serialization you heard about is exactly this, including all problems. About text formats: While easier, it´s not perfect either. Charset again, guaranteed ranges of values...

Comment: @user1488118 Have a look at ASN.1 and [BER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.690#BER_encoding). Or [BSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSON).

Comment: Text files? Really? The data overhead introduced by that would be enormous. These volumes are already about 80Gb in RAM. Concerning the binary encoding formats mentioned, are there any libraries that support doing this for you?

Comment: You have to use a floating point standard as IEEE 754 here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point

Note that depending on your platform, your ```float``` or ```double``` may or may not follow the IEEE 754 representation, so it is not just a matter of serializing the bytes of your variables.

Instead, you will need to platform-aware tool to con write/parse the IEEE 754 bits. I found this http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/advanced.html#serialization where some tools are provided, though they seem incomplete.

Comment: Qt apparently serializes certain data types when using the QDataStream, also float ("32-bit floating point number using the standard IEEE 754 format", http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/datastreamformat.html). Maybe I'll give that a try.

Comment: Normally medical images are saved as DICOM files. I would use an appropriate library (GDCM, DCMTK ...) to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem using the Qt `Datastream` class. Qt is part of my project anyway, so the additional effort is minimal. I can tell the `Datastream` object exactly if I want to save my `floats` using single precision (32bit) or double precision (64bit) and if I want to use little endian or big endian byte order. This is totally sufficient for what I need; I don't need to serialize objects. The files I save now have exactly the same format on all platforms (at least they should), and this is all I need. They will afterwards be read by 3rd party applications to which these information (byte order, precision) will be supplied. So to say it is not of importance exactly *how* my floats are saved but that I *know* how they are saved and that this is consistent no matter on which platform you run the program.

Here is how the code looks now:

```
QDataStream out(&file);
out.setFloatingPointPrecision(QDataStream::SinglePrecision);
out.setByteOrder(QDataStream::LittleEndian);

for (int x = 0; x < _xSize; ++x){
    for (int y = 0; y < _ySize; ++y){
        for (int z = 0; z < _zSize; ++z){
            //save one float of data
            out<<_volume[x][y][z];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Google Protocol Buffers: free, encodes to binary, available in several languages, works across most platforms too. For your requirements I would seriously consider GPB. Be careful though, Google have released several versions and they've not always been backward compatible, ie old data is not necessarily readable by new versions of GPB code. I feel that it's still evolving and further changes will happen, which could be a nuisance if your project is also going to evolve over many years.

ASN.1, the grandpa of them all, very good schema language (value and size constraints can be set which is a terrific way of avoiding buffer overruns and gives automatic validation of data streams provided the auto generated code is correct), some free tools, see [this page](https://ttsiodras.github.io/asn1.html) (mostly though they cost money). GPB's schema language is kind of a poor imitation of ASN.1's.

Comment: I had this idea before and talked to a collegue who has used Google Protocol Buffers before for serializing objects. However, to me it seems  too much of work overhead that is produced by creating proto files and running the compiler on them. Especially since it's not my goal to serialize whole objects but just to write some simple primitive data types. I now ended up using the Qt `Datastream` which apparently works pretty well and platform independent.

Comment: @user1488118 Fair enough! One advantage of using something like GPB is that it gives you a 'single point of truth', so that any program using it gets exactly the same objects and serialisation. If you're writing all you code in Qt, you can get the same 'single point of truth' by reusing code. For future reference the overhead of using GPB (or anything like it) is not so bad if the compilation is called as a pre-build step. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised there is no mention of the `<rpc/xdr.h>` header, for External Data Representation. I believe it is on all unixes, and may even work on Windows: https://github.com/ralight/oncrpc-windows/blob/master/win32/include/rpc/xdr.h

XDR stores all primitive data types in big endian, and takes care of the conversions for you.